# Mottie jQuery Tablesorter filters not loading on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm having a terrible hard time at trying to get the Mottie Tablesorter plugin to work properly on my HTML page.

I'm designing the front end of a website for someone, and I need the advanced filters provided with this plugin:
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html#demo

I have downloaded the files in .zip format, extracted them and placed them in my project, and made sure all the links work properly and that the page can read them.

I have copy/pasted the stuff from the demo with the multiple types of filters across all the columns  (in the code quotes) into my HTML page.

However, the second table header row inside the table header doesn't appear.

I can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Here's a screenshot of what gets rendered on the page + the offending code inside the web inspector of Safari: http://puu.sh/dqzNX.png

As you can see, the second table header looks like it is trying to display, but it's empty?

And it seems like it generates a search for searching by text, but is set to hidden (I don't know why)

And it also generates the correct amount of TH's, but all of them (apart from the first one) are empty!!

I've been banging my head against a wall over this for 4 days now and have no clue!

Can anyone else get this demo to work properly?

Many thanks for taking the time to read all of this!

Comment: So I looked into the errors that Safari was giving me in the web inspector, and it seems that part of the plugin is throwing an error saying:
http://puu.sh/dqO4c.png

However, I don't know why it is throwing that error, I have a feeling that because of this error JS just stops all together. (As it often does with errors!)

If anyone could shed some light on why this error is being thrown it would be a great help!

Comment: Are you loading jQuery UI? It would make it easier to help if you could [provide a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/) showing the problem.

Comment: @Mottie thanks for the reply, I have replicated the issue in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4767/

Thanks!

Comment: All I did was [add jQuery UI + CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4769/) - make sure you reset the search as that demo likely saved some filters that don't work.

Comment: Looks like I must not have been pulling jQuery UI into my project properly, as when I started from scratch it all looks like it's working now!

-- My bad, thanks for the help though, great table filtering!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I must not have been pulling jQuery UI into my project properly, as when I started from scratch it all looks like it's working now! -- My bad, thanks for the help though, great table filtering!

In my haste I also seemed to have put a css CDN into a script src tag, causing some style errors where the date picker was below the table before it had been selected and had a transparent background. That had me stumped for a good 20 minutes until I realised my mistake!